# rails block scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to count entries in this block.Because of ruby block variable scope,I don't handle with this code.Is there any way to fix this?

```
    arr_showcase.each do |entry|
          @entry = ContestEntry.find_by_id(entry)
          if @entry.view_in_showcase == true
            @entry.view_in_showcase = false
            @entry.save
            entry_added_showcase += 1 
          else
            @entry.view_in_showcase = true
            @entry.save
            entry_removed_showcase += 1 
          end
    end
    redirect_to :back, :notice => "#{entry_added_showcase} Desings added, #{entry_removed_showcase} Designs removed."
```

Comment: I want to count entries in the block and use them after the block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you declare the `entry_added_showcase` and `entry_removed_showcase`? you have to initialize them outside the block.

```
entry_added_showcase = entry_removed_showcase = 0
arr_showcase.each do |entry|
      @entry = ContestEntry.find_by_id(entry)
      if @entry.view_in_showcase == true
        @entry.view_in_showcase = false
        @entry.save
        entry_added_showcase += 1 
      else
        @entry.view_in_showcase = true
        @entry.save
        entry_removed_showcase += 1 
      end
end
redirect_to :back, :notice => "#{entry_added_showcase} Desings added, #{entry_removed_showcase} Designs removed."
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define your variables outside the scope of the block like this:

```
entry_added_showcase = 0
entry_removed_showcase = 0
arr_showcase.each do |entry|
      @entry = ContestEntry.find_by_id(entry)
      if @entry.view_in_showcase == true
        @entry.view_in_showcase = false
        @entry.save
        entry_added_showcase += 1 
      else
        @entry.view_in_showcase = true
        @entry.save
        entry_removed_showcase += 1 
      end
end
redirect_to :back, :notice => "#{entry_added_showcase} Desings added, #{entry_removed_showcase} Designs removed."
```